# I cant get the bittrex v3 api in C++ working

Tags: c++, api, curl

For the life of me I cannot get this to work. I have not been able to find example code for v3 of the Bittrex API so I have patched together what I've found for v1.1 and v3 in other programming languages.

I am using curl and openssl libraries.

I am getting a "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL" error.

```cpp
#include "../curl/curl.h"
#include <sha512.hh>
#include "hmac.h"
#include "sha.h"

string bittKey, bittSecret;
string timeStamp, hTTPMethod, uRI, requestBody, contentHash;

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();

bittKey =       "..."; 
bittSecret =    "...";
timeStamp = std::to_string(time(nullptr));
uRI = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/balances";
hTTPMethod = "GET";
requestBody = "";
contentHash = sw::sha512::calculate(requestBody);

string preSign = timeStamp + uRI + hTTPMethod + contentHash;
string apiSign = hmac_sha512(preSign, bittSecret);

struct curl_slist* headerList = NULL;

headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, "Accept: application/json");
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, "Content-Type: application/json");
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Api-Key: " + bittKey).c_str());
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Api - Signature: " + apiSign).c_str());
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Api-Timestamp: " + timeStamp).c_str());
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Api-Content-Hash: " + contentHash).c_str());

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, uRI);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerList);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

if (res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

curl_slist_free_all(headerList);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite a long time of searching and debugging through the curl libraries the solution was quite simple.

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, uRI.c_str());
```

Oh and the timestamp doesn't work the way I have it above. It works as follows:

```
    using namespace std::chrono;
    milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
        system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        );

    timeStamp = std::to_string(ms.count());
```

The API is working now.